# Is it possible to block website through system Linux firewall for browser that used DNS over HTTPS?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, hosts

OS: Fedora 34

Browser: Mozilla Firefox with DoH enabled

I'm trying to block website through core Linux settings (not web browser extension etc). Problem is inside DoH that I'm using. If I disable DoH, then all works perfectly with settings inside hosts

```bsh
# vi /etc/hosts


0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com
```

I was trying to edit iptables but that doesn't work too

```bsh
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d www.facebook.com --dport 443 -j DROP

# service iptables save

# service iptables restart

# iptables -L
```

As I understood it is impossible at system level to block my access to web addr?

Answer (score 1):

`iptables` **can** block by hostnames, from `man iptables`:

`-s, --source address Source  specification. Address  can  be either a network name, a hostname, a network IP address (with /mask), or a plain IP address.`

The reason why it doesn't work for you is because your `iptables` use a locally configured resolver to find out Facebook IP addresses while Firefox gets addresses from a different DNS provider. Since Facebook uses cloud, its IP addresses are **different** between DNS providers and geographical locations which ultimately means an `iptables` solution will unlikely to work.

Instead you could use group policies for Firefox to block websites, e.g. https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#websitefilter https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/releases

E.g. check this answer here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1260799

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this is best done at **both** the network layer and the application layer.  i.e. use simple `iptables` rules for the network layer, and a proxy for complex fine control of what's allowed and what isn't.

Set up a proxy (e.g. [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and block direct access to port 80 and 443 except for squid.

If your gateway/firewall is a moderately powerful Linux machine, squid can run on the same box.  You could run squid in a VM or a container but it's probably easier to just allocate a dedicated IP address for squid and make squid use it with the `tcp_outgoing_address` option in `squid.conf`. Only allow that IP address to connect to external hosts on those ports (either in an OUTPUT chain, or in a NAT chain if your LAN is using private addresses).

Otherwise, if you're using a dedicated linux-based router (e.g. running [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) or similar), **older** models with under-powered CPUs and insufficient RAM probably aren't capable, but most of the modern models made within the last 5 years or so are more than powerful enough. As is pretty much any server-class machine or re-purposed desktop made in the last 20 years or so.  Even a raspberry pi or similar would be fine if you need to run it on a dedicated machine.

Because you are configuring things so that only squid can access web sites, you can use the squid config to allow or deny particular hosts...optionally in conjunction with other programs like [squidguard](http://www.squidguard.org)

Also run your own caching DNS resolver (e.g. [unbound](https://www.unbound.net/)) and make sure that your squid box uses it - disable anything that messes with `/etc/resolv.conf` (including the crappy systemd-resolved abomination).  And remember to configure your client machines use your DNS resolver, either by static configs or via DHCP.

Comment: I'm very glad to see such detail and helpful answer! Thanks for the desire to help.